# move the label from left to right in table layout panel c#

Tags: c#, label, tablelayout

I have this code and when I run it, it has moved but has two label display on screen, one is no move, one has move

```
public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        int x = 25, y = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.SetBounds(x, y, 255, 255);
            x++;
            if (x >= 800)
            {
                x = 1;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "hii";
            label1.Font = new Font(" ", 22, FontStyle.Bold);
            timer1.Interval = 10;
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more label from toolbox to form. In timer set new label's bounds also like this:

```
    int x = 25, y = 1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.SetBounds(x, y, 255, 255);
        label2.SetBounds(x, 100, 255, 255);
        x++;
        if (x >= 800)
        {
            x = 1;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "hii";
        label1.Font = new Font(" ", 22, FontStyle.Bold);

        label2.Text = "hii2";
        label2.Font = new Font(" ", 22, FontStyle.Bold);

        timer1.Interval = 10;
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code and its working well. Maybe you added  one more label under the label1 please check it from properties tab.

Comment: u must add the label in table layout panel,if put the label at outside the page,it can be move but in table layout,it cant function

Comment: after my research, the table layout panel can't insert two things inside one box, so must have one panel to insert timer and label.then it runs probably